# Click on same link is appeding # in angular js

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app i have two links

```
<a href="#signup">signup</a>
<a href="#signin">signin</a>
```

When i click on signup link, the url in address bar becomes `localhost/signup`.
if i click the same link again, the url in address bar becomes `localhost/signup/#signup`

I could n't find any solution.
Can anyone help me please.

Route config:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/home/views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('/signup', {
            templateUrl: 'app/signup/views/signup.html',
            controller: 'SignUpController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: Normally angular links are like `#/signup`. Are you missing `/`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, If i add #/signup, the url becomes http://localhost:40/signup#%2Fsignup on second click

Comment: Please share your route configuration that you did using $routeProvider

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the hashtag for routing. Jus use `href="signup`.